# Bind unprivileged application to privileged port on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, tcp

I'd like to create launchd.plist file for an httpd server. Problem is - when the httpd is run as privileged user it daemonizes, which is not allowed by [launchd.plist manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html). If I don't run it as superuser - it cannot bind to privileged port (which is not necessary, but nice to have).

Question - what are my options for binding unprivileged daemon to a privileged port? I do know that Linux has [privbind](http://privbind.sourceforge.net/) project. Is there a solution that can be used together with Mac OS X's launchd? Can/Should I use privbind and hack it together with launchd.plist format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache supports [several special debugging defines](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Getting-Started-with-Apache/9/), to be used with -D:

- NO_DETACH: Don’t detach from the controlling terminal.
- FOREGROUND: (implies NO_DETACH): Don’t daemonize or detach from the controlling terminal
- ONE_PROCESS (implies NO_DETACH and FOREGROUND): Don’t allow a child process to handle client requests; use the initial process instead.
- DEBUG (implies all of the previous): Places the MPM into a special debug mode with additional logging.

Thus, running "httpd -D FOREGROUND" will keep it from daemonizing.

I also ran into [a forum thread with a launchd plist for Apache2](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=105085) that you might be able to adapt.

(Note: I know neither of these answer the actual question, but hopefully they're useful for the problem initially described.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, although I meant httpd in general sense as "http daemon". It's actually Mongrel2 which I'm spinning my head around .) But your answer does solve the problem for apache. Actually - Mac OS X has this built in and is controlled via "Web sharing" checkbox in sharing pref pane.

Comment: @Eimantas, I think you can register a listening Socket on port 80 and set the UserName to your unprivileged user; my understanding is that launchd will open that port itself and hand off connections to the daemon, so it doesn't need the privileges to open the port itself. [man launchd.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) has a lot of information.